# How to backup/restore in Fedora 13?

Tags: backup, restore, fedora-13

I'm a n00b when it comes to backing up and restoring my fedora 13 machine. I don't have anything particularly important on my machine right now, but part of the reason I put this OS on my laptop is to learn as much as possible.
So I'd like to start by learning how to backup (and later restore) my system. Do I need to download third party software or is there a pre-packaged utility that comes with Fedora 13?

Comment: You didn't find anything relevant in Add/Remove Software?

Comment: A lot of things come up when I search "backup". Do you have any recommendations/guidelines?

Comment: what is the most common way to backup a fedora system?

Comment: I rsync to another machine to back up my stuff, so I'm not really the person to ask about backup software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like the approach described by Jamie Zawinski:

http://www.jwz.org/doc/backups.html

It's not hard to set up and, most importantly, dead easy to restore.

Comment: Awesome. I'd give +1 if I had the rep. Thanks!

Comment: The document linked to says "...if you're using linux it's a lot like that..." No. It's not. Even if it was the answer given would be off-topic since we're talking about Fedora not Mac OS X. If the link is wrong then maybe it needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [rsync to backup your files](http://www.my-guides.net/en/guides/linux/87-how-to-backupsynchronize-your-files-using-rsync) onto an external device.

[Search "backup"](http://www.fedoraforum.org/) on fedora forums, one that is [mentioned](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1397360&postcount=6) is safekeep. There is also mention of [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org), I can't say what these are like though.